# Extend the dotCMS REST API

Tags: java, rest, plugins, dotcms

I'm new to dotCMS (actually I evaluat it for a project).

I created a custom type, for the sake of simplicity we can pretend that it's just a Message with a WYSIWYG content field.

Now I want to display this message in a web client app using the rest API.

So I get my messages with :

```
/api/content/query/+structureName:Message
```

and I got this (which is perfect) :

```
"contentlets":[{
    "owner":"dotcms.org.2831",
    "content":  "<p>Hi !<\/p>\n<p>I am a <strong>Message<\/strong>.<\/p>\n<p>See you.<\/p>",
    ...
    },{
    "owner":"dotcms.org.2831",
    ...
    }
]
```

Now I'm missing the owner public name and I can't get it with the standard rest API.
How am I supposed to do this ?

The closer I get is using the osgi plugin based on the spring example. And reading the sourcecode of the com.dotcms.rest package. I try to get it at app/spring/myController/test or app/spring/myController/getUserNameById/id/dotcms.org.2831 but no success (**EDIT**: I got a 404 not found and no errors in logs). Known issue are in the javadoc :

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@RequestMapping ("/myController")
@Controller
/**
 * I also try with @Path("/myController") but I got a 404 not found.
 **/
public class myController extends WebResource {

    /**
     * This default method works fine.
     **/
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        Logger.info( this.getClass(), "Received request to hello" );
        String myMessage = "Hello World, Spring 3.1 and dotCMS!";
        // This will resolve to /application/spring/helloworld.dot
        return new ModelAndView("helloworld", "message", myMessage);
    }

    /**
     * This one dosen't accept my MappingJacksonJsonView. But no error in the logfile.
     **/
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test() {
        Logger.info( this.getClass(), "Test request" );
        Map<String,String> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("key", "value");
        Logger.info( this.getClass(), "Map ready" );
        MappingJacksonJsonView view = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
        Logger.info( this.getClass(), "View ready" );
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(view, model);
        Logger.info( this.getClass(), "Response ready" );
        return modelAndView;
    }

    /**
     * I can't reach this method. And if so, will the Response return type even work ?
     **/
    @GET
    @Path("/getUserNameById/{params:.*}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getUserById(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("params") String params) throws JSONException {

        InitDataObject initData = init( params, true, request, true );

        Map<String, String> paramsMap = initData.getParamsMap();
        String userId = paramsMap.get("id");
        Logger.info( this.getClass(), "Received request with userId " + userId );

        //Creating an utility response object
        ResourceResponse responseResource = new ResourceResponse( initData.getParamsMap() );

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("userId", userId);
        //Get and put user public name into the jsonObject here.
        Logger.info( this.getClass(), jsonObject.toString());
        return responseResource.response(jsonObject.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: "but no success" doesn't tell us anything. What happens when you try?

Comment: You'r right, sorry. I can't reach the endpoint, I got a 404 not found and no errors in logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Jersey osgi example provided.  It allows you to extend and add new endpoints to the dotCMS rest API.  See:

https://github.com/dotCMS/core/tree/master-3.2/docs/examples/osgi/com.dotcms.rest

Comment: That's exactly what I expected. I can't belewe I missed it. Thanks. It would be nice if every example were listed in the documentation : http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/osgi-plugins